# Proof of an "Elementary" Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, complex-numbers

Let $d\geq 1, l \geq 1$ be integers. I am trying to prove the following inequality to complete a step in a proof of a PDE problem I read in a paper:

> There exists a constant $C_{d,l}<\infty$ and $\theta\in (0,1)$ such that for all $(z_{1},\ldots,z_{l})\in\mathbb{C}^{l}$,
>   $$\left||\sum_{j=1}^{l}z_{j}|-|\sum_{j=1}^{l}|z_{j}|^{\frac{2(d+2)}{d}}|^{\frac{d}{2(d+2)}}\right|\leq C_{d,l}\sum_{{1\leq j,j'\leq l}\atop{j\neq j'}}|z_{j}|^{\theta}|z_{j'}|^{1-\theta}$$

I have also seen the inequality

> $$\left||\sum_{j=1}^{l}z_{j}|^{p}-\sum_{j=1}^{l}|z_{j}|^{p}\right|\leq C_{l}\sum_{j\neq j'}|z_{j}||z_{j'}|^{p-1},$$

where $p>2$ is real, in related papers. The second inequality would probably suffice for my purposes.

Obviously, the inequality is not hard when $p$ is an integer and $z_{j}$ are real since algebraic manipulations are available.

For noninteger $p$, I tried convexity arguments but was unsuccessful. I though about proving it by induction on $l$, but I am not sure how to proceed on the inductive step.

---

**Edit**: I think I have a solution; comments are welcome.

Say we have two complex numbers $a,b$. First, I claim that we may without loss of generality assume that $a,b$ are real. Indeed,
$$\left||a+b|^{p}-|a|^{p}-|b|^{p}\right|=\begin{cases} |a+b|^{p}-|a|^{p}-|b|^{p}\leq ||a|+|b||^{p}-|a|^{p}-|b|^{p}\\ |a|^{p}+|b|^{p}-|a+b|^{p}\leq |a|^{p}+|b|^{p}-||a|-|b||^{p}\end{cases}$$

By FTC,

$$|a+b|^{p}-|a|^{p}=\int_{0}^{1}p|a+tb|^{p-1}bdt,$$

whence
$$|a+b|^{p}-|a|^{p}-|b|^{p}=\int_{0}^{1}p(|a+tb|^{p-1}-|tb|^{p-1})bdt$$
If we apply FTC once more to the integrand, we get

$$\int_{0}^{1}p(|a+tb|^{p-1}-|tb|^{p-1})bdt=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}p(p-1)|as+tb|^{p-2}(ab)dsdt$$

Taking the modulus of both sides and using convexity,

\begin{align*}
|\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}p(p-1)|as+tb|^{p-2}(ab)dsdt|&\lesssim_{p}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}(|as|^{p-2}+|bt|^{p-2})|ab|dsdt\\
&\lesssim_{p}|a|^{p-1}|b|+|b|^{p-1}|a|
\end{align*}

If $a=\sum_{j=1}^{l}z_{j}$ and $b=z_{l+1}$, then the above yields

\begin{align*}
\left||\sum_{j=1}^{l+1}z_{j}|^{p}-\sum_{j=1}^{l+1}|z_{j}|^{p}\right|&\leq C_{p}\left[|z_{l+1}||\sum_{j=1}^{l}z_{j}|^{p-1}+|z_{l+1}|^{p-1}|\sum_{j=1}^{l}z_{j}|\right]
\end{align*}

For the first term, we use the inductive hypothesis and triangle inequality to write

\begin{align*}
|z_{l+1}||\sum_{j=1}^{l}z_{j}|^{p-1}&\leq C_{l,p-1}|z_{l+1}|\sum_{{1\leq j,j'\leq l}\atop{j\neq j'}}|z_{j}|^{p-2}|z_{j'}|+|z_{l+1}|\sum_{j=1}^{l}|z_{j}|^{p-1}
\end{align*}

Write
$$|z_{l+1}|\sum_{{1\leq j,j'\leq l}\atop{j\neq j'}}|z_{j}|^{p-2}|z_{j'}|=|z_{l+1}|\sum_{j'=1}^{l}\sum_{{1\leq j\leq l}\atop{j\neq j'}}|z_{j}|^{p-2}|z_{j'}|$$
Let $j_{0}=j_{0}(j')$ be such that $|z_{j_{0}}|=\max_{1\leq j\leq l+1, j\neq j'}|z_{j}|$. Then $$|z_{l+1}||z_{j}|^{p-2}|z_{j'}|\leq |z_{j_{0}}|^{p-1}|z_{j'}|$$
So
\begin{align*}
|z_{l+1}|\sum_{{1\leq j,j'\leq l}\atop{j\neq j'}}|z_{j}|^{p-2}|z_{j'}|&\leq\sum_{j'=1}^{l}|z_{j'}|l|z_{j_{0}}|^{p-1}\\
&\leq l^{2}\sum_{{1\leq j,j'\leq l+1}\atop{j\neq j'}}|z_{j'}||z_{j}|^{p-1}
\end{align*}
Combining this estimate with the above estimates completes the proof of the inductive step.